# Twilio Voice API recites mp3 URL instead of playing the mp3 music

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am playing with Twilio Voice API and have a callback URL to my application whenever an answering machine/human is detected. The mp3 I am trying to play works fine through Twiml Runtime Bin. However, when application responds with the Twiml, twilio always recites the URL instead of playing the music.

```
public void makeOutBoundCall()
{
    Twilio.init(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_ACCOUNT_TOKEN);

    CallCreator callCreator = new CallCreator(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, new PhoneNumber(TO_NUMBER),
            new PhoneNumber(TWILIO_NUMBER),
            URI.create(APP_URL + TwilioVoiceApplication.TWILIO_AMD_CALLBACL_URL))
                    .setMachineDetection("DetectMessageEnd")
                    .setMachineDetectionTimeout(20000);
    callCreator.create();
} 


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String amdCallback(@RequestParam Map<String, String> queryMap) throws Exception
{
    // Default behavior hangup the call
    Hangup hangup = new Hangup();
    VoiceResponse voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse.Builder().hangup(hangup)
            .build();
    if (queryMap.containsKey("AnsweredBy"))
    {
        if (queryMap.get("AnsweredBy")
                .equals("human"))
        {
            voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse.Builder()
                    .say(new Say.Builder("Hello Monkey").build())
                    .play(new Play.Builder("http://demo.twilio.com/hellomonkey/monkey.mp3")
                            .build())
                    .build();
        }
    }
    return voiceResponse.toString();
}
```

Comment: The problem was with the response header, adding "content-type: text/xml", fixed the problem

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! I actually recommend you add this as an answer below and accept it. It makes it easier for others to see the solution if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/xml")
public ResponseEntity<String> amdCallback(@RequestParam Map<String, String> queryMap)
            throws Exception
    {
    // Default behavior hangup the call
    Hangup hangup = new Hangup();
    VoiceResponse voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse.Builder().hangup(hangup)
            .build();
    if (queryMap.containsKey("AnsweredBy"))
    {
        if (queryMap.get("AnsweredBy")
                .equals("human"))
        {
            voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse.Builder()
                    .say(new Say.Builder("Hello Monkey").build())
                    .play(new Play.Builder("http://demo.twilio.com/hellomonkey/monkey.mp3")
                            .build())
                    .build();
        }
    }
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //Add the content-type:text/html in response header
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml");

    ResponseEntity<String> response = ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .body(voiceResponse.toXml());
    return response;
}
```